# jar files not being downloaded only .pom files using m2eclipse and Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, rad, artifactory

I using RAD 7.5 as the IDE and have the m2eclipse 0.10 plugin installed.

I've installed a fresh copy of the IDE but when I try to check out our project from SVN, it only downloads the .pom and .pom.sha1 files from our Artifactory, this also happens to every maven plugin it tries to fetch. So the end result is complains of missing artifacts and a local repo full of .pom and .pom.sha1 files.

I have an identical work space on another machine that has no issues and correctly downloads the jars as need, I've even used my own settings.xml.

However if create a new Maven Project and add dependency into the project, it fetches the jar and any other transitive dependencies successfully, so now that jar is in my local repo but still the other project says its not there.

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: There is a chance either .project , .classpath or files under .settings folder are corrupted.  This can happen when plugins change, new eclipse reading from old eclipse, workspace. Try removing these files/folders and importing projects again from start. Also you might think of updating your M2E plugin if possible.

Comment: we don't commit the eclipse generated project files, so in svn only the source code, resources, etc are committed.

Unfortunately 0.10 is the most latest release that can be used as RAD 7.5 is based on eclipse 3.4.2 and we can't change the version of RAD we are using.

Comment: .project,.classpath and .settings should not be in svn. Only the pom.xml is necessary in svn and project import is done using maven & eclipse with m2e using this pom.xml.

Comment: that is how we have it setup, so none of the eclipse files are committed these are generated based on the setup of the pom.xml when we check out the project. so those .files will be freshly generated.

Comment: any chance the workspace .metadata folder/files are corrupted ?

Comment: not sure how i can find if they have been corrupted. I tried starting from a new workspace, so when I checkout the project it will a freshly generated set of .metadata files.

Comment: and did the new workspace work?

Comment: no still complains of missing artifacts, just don't understand why it can find the .pom file be then doesn't attempt to download the associated jar.

Comment: any chance the m2e settings file is wrong? Eclipse -> Preferences -> Maven